# How to update a Hyperlink collection automatically if user removes one?

Tags: c#, wpf, hyperlink, .net-4.0, richtextbox

Could you tell me how to do this? Or is it WPF-impossible?

- load a small or large FlowDocument (containing text and Hyperlinks) into a RichTextBox
- store all Hyperlinks in a container (in UI not visible), maybe a `List<Hyperlink>`
- container should be updated automatically if user removes a Hyperlink by keyboard

I want to avoid dealing with KeyDown and TextChanged events. 
Then I would have to handle Delete key, Backspace key, Cut, typing into a selected text area, Undo, Redo.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know two-way databinding?

Comment: I think I need a binding between the at runtime changing Hyperlinks of a RichTextBox and the underlying list. But how to do? Could you give more details?